# auto compute of <input> using the 'class='classname'' using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Can some one help me, i need to compute 'AUTOMATICALLY' `<input>` that has the same `class=` and output into another `<input id=>`, this is what i've tried so far

```
$('.debit').change(function(e)  {
    var total = 0;
    total +=  parseFloat(this.value);
    $('#total').val(total);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by `auto compute`?

Comment: Also add your `html` code

Comment: if someone input a data on `<input>` it will automatically output the sum to another <input>

Comment: <input type='text' name='debit' class='debit' id='debit"+x+"' placeholder='debit' style='width:60px'>

Comment: <input readonly  type='text' name='total_debit_text' id='total' style='width: 60px'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.debit').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var total = 0;
    $('.debit').each(function () {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    });

    $('#total').val(total);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rvba2r2o/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, get all input with `.debit` class name using `.each` like so :

```
$('.debit').change(function (e) {
  var total = 0;
  $('.debit').each(function(){
     var myValue = $(this).val() ? $(this).val() : 0;
     total += parseFloat(myValue);
  });      
  $('#total').val(total);
});

//or use keyup

$('.debit').keyup(function (e) {
   var total = 0;   
   $('.debit').each(function(){
     var myValue = $(this).val() ? $(this).val() : 0;
     total += parseFloat(myValue);
   });      
   $('#total').val(total);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/0bzbjzgw/1/)**

p/s : it could be better if you use .keyup instead of change.

Comment: @Paul : Nan because there is no initial value for input. You should see the `Tushar` answer